# How to return google sheet values using doPost using x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, post

I try to use google sheets to write and read some data using post requests,
the writing part works, but it never returns any value back.

```
function doPost(e) { return handleResponse(e); }

function handleResponse(e) {
    
  // Get public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  // (https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html)
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  
  // Allow the write process up to 2 seconds
  lock.waitLock(2000);

  try {
    
    // Generate a (not very good) UUID for this submission
    var submissionID = e.parameter.id || 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
    // Open the spreadsheet document and select the right sheet page
    var sheetName = e.parameter.sheet_name|| 'Sheet1';
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    //get information out of post request
    var action = e.parameter.action || 'save';
    var pName = e.parameter.name;
    var rowNumber = findRow(pName,sheetName);
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(headRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    

    // check for action is loading
    if(action == 'load'){
      //check if the name has data
      if (rowNumber){

        //loads all the give values out of the parameters
        var answer = [];
        Logger.log('hadders: ' + headers);
        for (i in headers) {
            if (e.parameter[headers[i].toLowerCase()] !== undefined) {
              var val = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0][i];
              answer.push(val);
            }
          }
          Logger.log('answer: '+ answer);
          // Return result in JSON
          return ContentService
            .createTextOutput({body:{parameter:{answer}}})
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          ;
      }else{
          // return error name wasn't found in sheet.
          return ContentService
          .createTextOutput("can't find Name")
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
          ;
      }
  
    }
```

The logger returns all the right values,
but logging the return value from this function ends up in an empty object.

I tried just making my own return object like:

```
return ContentService
          .createTextOutput({body={parameter={answer=JSON.stringify(answer)}}})
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
          ;
```

I know that I need to use `&=` instead of `,:` but it still returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
return ContentService
  .createTextOutput({body:{parameter:{answer}}})
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
```

#### To:

```
return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({body:{parameter:{answer}}}))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
```

- In the case of `createTextOutput({body:{parameter:{answer}}})`, the object cannot be directly put. So I thought that it is required to convert it to the string.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: I tried this sadly with no positive result.
Also tried to access the web app via "thunder client" and it returns me a 405 error.
So I'm guessing that I have to change something about my access I redeploy every time with "Who has access" = Anyone.

Comment: @K.Tchoul33 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and also I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your current situation from `I tried this sadly with no positive result.`. Because when I tested the modified script, if the if statement is true, the result value is obtained. In order to correctly understand it, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, did you relect the modified script to your Web Apps?

Comment: I changed the code to this:
`          return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({response:answer}))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)`
But the source of the post request still returns "error" as responding value.

Comment: @K.Tchoul33 Thank you for replying. I cannot know the value of `e` for correctly replicating your issue in your script, and also I cannot know your function `findRow`. So I cannot test your script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. By this, can you confirm whether both `action == 'load'` and `rowNumber` are `true`? When both values are `true`, my proposed script is run. Because in the case of `the source of the post request still returns "error" as responding value.`, I thought that `rowNumber` is `false`.